# res.status not a function when trying to set the status code

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, sinon

When attempting to meet the specification set by unit tests supplied, when attempting to return the status code for a method I am hit with

> TypeError: res.status is not a function

when running the function createUser in the API implementation. It happens with every method call, such as res.send, res.sendStatus etc. Even if I add res.status() to the testing to set it there, it returns the same error.

apiTests.js

```
let chai = require('chai');
let expect = chai.expect;
let sinon = require('sinon');
let sinonChai = require('sinon-chai');
chai.use(sinonChai);

let model = require('../tron_model.js'); // for stubbing only
let api = require('../tron_api.js');

describe('API', function() {
    describe('creating users', function() {
        it('should return 201 on creating user', function () {
            let mockModel = sinon.stub(new model.TronModel());
            mockModel.addUser.onFirstCall().returns(new model.User('user','pass'));
            let req = {body: {username: 'goatzilla', password: 'x'}};
            let res = {end: function(){}};
            api.init(mockModel);
            api.createUser(req, res);
            expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(201);
            expect(mockModel.addUser).to.have.callCount(1);
        });
    });
});
```

tron_api.js

```
let model = undefined;
let api = exports;

api.init = function(modelArg) {
    model = modelArg;
};

api.createUser = function(req, res) {
    model.addUser(req.body.username, req.body.password);
    console.log(res);
    res.status(201);
};
```

Comment: `let res = {end: function(){}};` ... yep, the `res` you created has a single function, `end` - where did you think `status` was going to come from?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You mocked a `res` object with this code:

```
let res = {end: function(){}};
```

that does not have a `.status()` method and then passed that to your `api.createUser()` function which expects to call `res.status()` (a method that is not on your mocked object).  A mocked object will need to have every method on it that your code calls.

In addition, you are also testing the property `res.statusCode` with this:

```
expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(201);
```

which also does not exist on your mocked object.  While `res.status()` is a built-in capability in Express, `res.statusCode` is not a documented property (though it does appear to exist).

You could add to your mocked `res` object like this:

```
let res = {
    end: function(){}
    status: function(s) {this.statusCode = s; return this;}
};
```

To get it to pass those two tests.

Comment: @DavidWood - Since it appears you may be new here, if this answered your question, then you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points here for following the proper procedure.